# Drawing lots triangles by calling glDrawElements() becomes slow?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
{
    model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(i * 2, i * 2 , i * 2));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modellocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void *)0);
}
```

here is a part of my code.

I want to draw 100000000 triangles but it becomes very slow. 
I know it is because I called `glDrawElements` so many time. And I also know that I need to draw more triangles in one time to avoid calling `glDrawElements` too many time.

But I don't understand how to so that, am I need to change the Buffer I have Bound or can I use another way to do that?

here is my Buffer

```
float vertex[] = {
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};
```

And my index buffer

```
unsigned int indices[] = {     0, 1, 2    };
```

And I Bind the buffer like this

```
unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Comment: `glDraw` calls involve significant overhead. As @AdrianRoman's answer says, combine your triangles into a single buffer and issue a single draw call.

Comment: It's slow because it is drawing one triangle at a time.  It's also slow because the model view matrix is being updated for every triangle.  Also there wouldn't be enough memory to simply create a list of all the verticies / indicies required for that many triangles.  A balance between all of it is required.  Any good book or online tutorial can show you how to make the basic funciton calls to draw more than one triangle at a time.

Comment: I know that I can use glBufferSubData to add some buffer,but each of the triangle have a different position.how can I put all the triangles into a buffer? So I just use glUniformMatrix4fv to change the model every time when I draw a new triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can put more than one triangle in a vertex buffer and 'draw' them all at once. Here is an example of a sphere made from many triangles: [SolarSystem](https://github.com/aromanro/SolarSystem/blob/master/SolarSystem/Sphere.cpp)
You could grab my project from GitHub and look over it, it might help.

Also there is another method that can speed up things greatly, instancing. It's not used in the SolarSystem project, but I used it in the Event Driven Molecular Dynamics project.

Comment: It's best to quote the linked page. The link might not remain active...

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192).

Comment: I'm quite sure that a few clicks could help the user find those usage notes and so on. There is a blog entry for that project.